# Site visits, heat maps, device activities etc. are not updating on Presence Insights analytics console

Tags: analytics, ibm-cloud, presenceinsights

Site visits, visits by zone, visit density, heat map, device activities none of these details are displayed on the Presence Insights analytics console for my site.I have uploaded a sample floor map, marked a zone and configured a beacon for the zone through the management console. I am using estimote beacon and iOS 8 device with the pi-sample-ios-BeaconSensing-master app running on it.

I can see the inbound beacon events on the analytics console under operations tab. Am I missing some configuration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have for the threshold on the beacon in the PI UI? The threshold is how close to the beacon you need to be in order for it to register (as determined by the "accuracy" attribute in the beacon payload). Also, what do you have in the zone setting for dwell time?

Comment: Threshold in meters: 10, Dwell Period (milliseconds): 5000. I can see the inbound beacon events on the analytics console under operations tab. All the counters in the analytics dashboard are showing as zero. Even the total sites under the overview tab is showing as zero. I tried with "All Time" and all other options available in the filter drop down list on the top right of the screen. The counters are still showing as zero.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to your question, within the Operations -> logs section of the dash board do you see any error messages ?
Also, in the images you have included, you have not shown the details for the beacon. Have you added the Beacon details into your instance of Presence Insights, including the UUID, major and minor values, and these must match those of the device you are detecting. 
Also, for your site which you defined, you can pull up analytics for that site via the first icon on the site line ( under the Management tab). Do you get any values from this selection.

Comment: I am not seeing any errors under operations -> logs. Yes I have already configured the beacon specifying the uuid, major and minor values and I can see the inbound beacon events under operations -> analytics tab. The ios demo app with PI SDK is successfully detecting the beacon and the events are recorded in presence insights. I think the Issue is with the analytics dashboard. All counters on my sites dashboard are showing zero including the "Total Sites" counter. I tried via the first icon on the site line as well.

Comment: The Total Sites counter, does not reflect the number of sites you have configured, but the number of sites that are detecting / receiving updates.

Comment: Thus is for some reason your transmitted input is not being accepted and correlated to an actual site / floor / zone, then no input will be registered with the analytics.

Comment: I have not myself tested, but will ask one of my colleagues to do so with sending in a incorrect payload for Beacons, but know when an incorrect payload is sent from swagger for the  Zebra or Cisco connector then the payload is shown in the logs. If the payload is seen as correctly formatted no error will be seen, even if the data within the payload is incorrect, i.e. X or Y values outside a zone or floor map for a floor.

Comment: The exception is for the names of the floor / site, when if no floor or site is found due to data error PI does create an entry in the log. 
The data in the operations tab, just defines that an data payload was received, not that it could be correlated to a floor or zone.

Comment: I would recommend trying to send a location packet into your system via swagger or Chromes 'Postman' app.
If this still fails we may need to contact you for your tenant id, so that we can check the payloads being received.

Comment: I think the transmitted input is being accepted and it is getting correlated to the actual site/floor/zone because, the event subscription I have configured for a particular site -> floor -> zone is working and I can see the outbound events under operations analytics.I have hosted the pi-sample-nodejs-eventing-master demo app in bluemix and provided its URL in the create subscription popup. I am using estimote beacon and iOS8  device having the pi-sample-ios-BeaconSensing-master app running on it.

Comment: I agree that if you are seeing subscription events, then the input data seems to have been correlated to an actual site -> floor -> zone.
Our next action will be to try and replicate your environment and see if we also have the same issue.